# Difference-in-Difference Model Using Historical Data

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am attempting to make a difference-in-difference model using individual wage data for college graduates before and after they graduated. The model that I am attempting to make looks something like `y=\beta{0} +\beta{1}D^post +\beta<sub>1 +\beta{2}D^tr  +\beta{2}D^tr +\beta{3}D^tr * D^post`.

The problem that I am having is finding a way to set it up without having high collinearity. For instance, I am currently doing the regression as such

```
y <- WAGES_QUART
d.post <- ifelse(assoc$GRAD_QUART >= QUARTER, 0, 1)
d.treated <- ifelse(assoc$GRAD_QUART >= QUARTER, 0,1)
dd <- assoc$d.post*assoc$d.treated
```

However, the way the data is set up, the post and treated have a collinearity of 1, so when running the regression

```
diff.in.diff <- lm(y ~ d.post + d.treated + dd)
```

The results are

```
Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   7633.4      681.2   11.21  < 2e-16 ***
d.post        4831.5      800.0    6.04 1.55e-09 ***
d.treated         NA         NA      NA       NA    
dd                NA         NA      NA       NA
```

The high collinearity makes sense but I have never done a difference-in-difference model only looking at one population before and after a particular time period. Should I be setting up the variables differently? Is this kind of difference-in-difference model set up differently? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to find out? Maybe you're making the model more complicated than it needs to be. Even though salaries before and after may be highly correlated, aren't you _really interested in the _differences?_ // Maybe start with a simple paired test (t or Wilcoxon depending on data),, see if you get interesting results. Then bring in additional features as seems warranted.

Comment: Can you explain what `d.post` and `d.treated` represent? According to your code, it suggests they both index the periods “after” students graduate.

Comment: Yes, they both equal the same thing. I have done diff-in-diff estimations in the past where I had two populations, a control and a treated group. The reason why I am confused on how to set this model up is because I am using the same population just at different periods of time. I did what BruceET recommended but it doesn't appear to be as robust as I would like it to be. Ideally, I would like to incorporate an age and age^2 variable as well as looking to see if ethnicity would change the wages that were observed. The paired t-test does a good job but I would like to do a regression if posible

Comment: The *same group* but at *different* periods of time? I suppose you want to compare one cohort of students across time with themselves at some distant time period in the past. This has been done before, but I am hesitant labeling it a difference-in-differences design. The reason for this is clear: we should be observing one **exposed** group and one **unexposed** group before *and* after treatment. Note, the term "post-treatment" should index the same time periods in both groups.

Answer (score 0):

Before even considering your code, your specification includes redundant terms. For example, your treatment dummy $D_{i}^{tr}$ is specified twice. Unless you have multiple treatment groups, $D_{i}^{tr}$ should only appear once; it should equal 1 for students in your treatment group, 0 otherwise. Here is the basic structure:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}D_{i}^{tr} + \beta_{2}D_{t}^{post} + \beta_{3}(D_{i}^{tr} \times D_{t}^{post}) + u_{it}
$$

where the right-hand side consists of a treatment dummy (i.e., $D_{i}^{tr}$), a pre-/post-graduation time indicator (i.e.,$D_{t}^{post}$), and the product of these two terms. Your causal estimand is $\beta_{3}$.

Upon review of your code, it appears you have *self-induced* collinearity. To be precise, you're estimating the product of two time dummies, both of which index the quarters after graduation. The variable $D_{i}^{tr}$ cannot be estimated; it's indistinguishable from your intercept. It's no surprise that R is only returning the main effect for post-treatment. In order for this to work, you should be observing at least two groups before *and* after graduation. One group should make it to commencement while the other does not. The unexposed group *is* the control group. In your setting, however, all students in your sample make to commencement—and in the same time period. In the absence of a viable control group, your counterfactual is simply the pre-graduation wages of *treated* students. We can't impute the earnings of students never attaining a university degree over the same time period because we only observe the "treated" state of the world. Is it possible to acquire data on individual wages for those students who dropped out of university? This should be something for you to consider.

The lack of suitable controls is one of the more apparent reasons why difference-in-differences is inappropriate. But other more subtle reasons exist as well. Note how your "milestone treatment" (i.e., matriculation/graduation) is a decision under the control of the individual, yet in most difference-in-differences applications the event under evaluation is usually **outside the control of the unit of observation**. Is "graduation" really your focus? I suppose this would require us to know more about your research question. What about the pay differential between students attending public versus parochial institutions, or the difference in earnings over time between students entering into STEM versus non-STEM degree programs?

In short, it'll be difficult to exploit this single "event" in the absence of a control cohort. Maybe heed the advice of @BruceET in the comments. First, try looking at the *differences* pre-/post-event. Once you get a handle on this, you can start investigating other more interesting factors which might explain why some cohorts *outearn* others. Even though they all graduate from university, interesting features about their birth cohort, study habits, relationship status, family size, personality, and health may all play a factor in how much they earn over time.